# How to output (date value from PHP) on jQuery ui date/timepicker input field?

Tags: php, jquery, uidatepicker

For my datetime field I used jQuery date/timepicker.

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

This worked fine.

But on the update form, when I try to output date from database on this date/timepicker input field, it does not work. When I inspect the element the date value is there (in correct ui date/timepicker format) as shown in the image below:

[image: Output issue on UI date/timepicker field]

How can I make date value from PHP appear on datepicker field ?

Comment: how are you setting the value on the field? can you show us the code?

Comment: When you `print_r($_POST);` to see what's posted, is the date not there?

Comment: @popnoodles I've tested echoing date, its fine. Even the datetime format is exact same as uidatepicker fromat. When I inspect element I can see `value ="2013-02-01 23:30:20"`

Comment: Oh sorry the problem is the other way round not on post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the value of the generated input field, pass in a *defaultValue* argument when you're creating the picker.  See the [Options tab, other options](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/), i.e.

```
defaultValue
    Default: null - String of the default time value placed in the input on focus when the input is empty.
```

This looks like it may only work when selected (e.g. it says "on focus").

Alternatively, while I'm not familiar with timepicker, you should be able to use the [setDate() method](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) to set the date/time, with something like this in a `$(document).ready` or similiar:

```
$( ".selector" ).datetimepicker( "setDate", "<?php echo $time_date?>" );
```

Comment: If I'm reading that right, the textbox will show as empty until you click it, *then* it will pre-select the specified day.

Comment: You were right... Just deleted my answer. I couldn't find any specific timepicker option for that. defaultValue says "on focus", that's why I left it outside.

Comment: @Mark you might be right.  IF that's the case, then the setDate() method will need to be used.  The jQuery datepicker doesn't use the value attribute to track the stored data, which is why the OPs current solution isn't working.

Comment: @ernie That way I would need to use AJAX.

Comment: @MrGhimire You don't need to use AJAX, just javascript . . . in your onReady or similar, you'll have to call the setDate() on your timepicker object, using the value you have in your PHP.  I've updated my answer to show this

Comment: cool that worked. you don't need quotes, I did this, `setDate:<?php echo $time_date?>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that. The jQuery Datepicker disables input field value unless it is hardcoded in the field value. If you are using populating from DB or something, use below method. It can be done using [setDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) function. as follows:-

```
$( "#your_input_id" ).datepicker( "setDate", "<?php echo $date_value;?>" );
```

it will work for both date only and date with time fields. It automatically fits to the value that your calender is formatted to.

Answer (score -1):

Just use PHP's `date()` function to format the `value` attribute in the same way that jQuery does.

Comment: I did this, `$time_date = date("Y-m-d H:s:i", strtotime($row['time_date']));` which the format on uidatetimepicker as well.

Comment: @MrGhimire: Works fine with jQuery UI Datepicker: http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/ExQGX/1/ If it doesn't work with your modified library, it sounds bugged to me.